# Toggling what is viewed when using an app

Tags: ios, swift, frames

I am fairly new to swift and iOS programming, and I've been watching video tutorials of people making things visible and not visible. When it comes to large scale projects I am start to doubt that they have one million features toggling between visible and not visible on the tiny screen.

So my question is, is I am making a tiny app how do I transition from basic view such as logging into a game and changing the login view to actually ingame. How do these type of things work?

Comment: your question not so cleared one side you are asking about toggling or hide and visible and on other end you are asking segue view-controllers

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is the basics of programming on Apple platforms. This can't be simply explained in a single answer. Please, start reading [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214) tutorial from Apple to get the understanding of the MVC concept and storyboards.

In short. You use the storyboard in Xcode to build your screens. Each screen is a scene in your program and represents a view controller. The view controller organizes how data is displayed on a screen and how to react to user input. You can create view controllers in code in Xcode and link these to the scenes (that are also view controllers) in the storyboard. In the code you can program the behavior of the different views that you put in each scene. Moving from onze scene to another is done with segues.

A segue can be made programmatically, you drag iT from onze view controller to the other. Or, in the storyboard boy dragging it from, e.g., from a button to the next view controller. You give the segue na identificeren and in prepare for segue (a method) you can program what data needs to be transferred from the existing to the destination view controller.